# How do I limit a Kafka client to only access one customer's data?

Tags: apache-kafka, authorization, acl

I'm evaluating Apache Kafka for publishing some event streams (and commands) between my services running on machines.

However, most of those machines are owned by customers, on their premises, and connected to their networks.

I don't want a machine owned by one customer to have access to another customer's data.

I see that Kafka has an [access control module](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-11+-+Authorization+Interface), which looks like it lets you restrict a client's access based on topic.

So, I could create a **topic per customer** and restrict each customer to just their own topic. This seems like a bad idea that I could regret in the future, because I've seen things that recommend restricting the number of Kafka topics to the 1000s at most.

Another design is to create a **partition per customer**. However, I don't see a way to restrict access if I do that.

Is there a way out of this quandary?

Comment: Well, you could look at the models of Confluent Cloud or Azure Event Hub... SASL+SSL certs are given to clients per account, and topics are created using those. You shouldnt assume a customer has a 1:1 mapping to a topic, for example, they use Kafka Streams to do some map/filter, then you've got more topics

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to achieve multi-tenancy in the context of Kafka and storm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23516427/how-to-achieve-multi-tenancy-in-the-context-of-kafka-and-storm)

Comment: The magic words I needed to know were __multiple tenancy__.

Comment: That's not exactly about limiting access, though. Rather just enforcing a naming convention of topics

Comment: I think probably the real answer is that I will end up either waiting for Kafka to get support for this stuff before using it, or I will use Apache Polaris instead.

Comment: Hmm. Never heard of Polaris

Comment: He means Apache Pulsar. It has multi-tenancy built in.